# How to fire an alarm after 2 seconds on iPhone

Tags: iphone, alarm

I want to fire an alarm that will ring after 2 secs. How to handle alarm code.
Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends what do you mean by an `alarm`...

If you want a popup alert after a while, you can use [Local Notification](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), which is an iOS 4 feature. An example can be found [here](http://icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/).

If you need certain function to be invoked by a timer, try [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-1059). Here is an [example](http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/28/iphone-programming-tutorial-animating-a-ball-using-an-nstimer/).

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the NSTimer class

Comment: thanks but what timer do?? i mean i want exactly like alram or can i open iphone clock form my application ??  or just play a sound but i still  want my alarm to be active even if user quits app. lets say he fixed a alarm after 5 mins so even if he close the app alarm will ring after 5 min

Comment: If you just need an action to be triggered by the application 2 seconds after the app launches then you should use NSTimer. But after your comment it sounds like you need to use Local Notification so that the alarm is triggered by the OS even if the application isn't running.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/IPhoneOSClientImp/IPhoneOSClientImp.html